LogIn automático en un Iframe
Necesito para mi trabajo final de la universidad que desde una web que yo desarrolle pueda acceder a otras cuadro mediante un iframe dentro la mía pero el detalle esta en que requiero que en las cuatro el login sea automático sin que el usuario tenga que hacer algo, es decir que cuando se cargue cada iframe la web debe iniciar sesión inmediatamente. Llevo varios dias intentando resolver solo esto y no encuentro una manera de implementarlo en mi web por los CORS e intente con librerías de web scrapping pero requiero solamente la automatización en esa parte, esta desarrollada en angular 17
Requiero una respuesta antes del 30 de este mes porfavor

Bienvenido a esta comunidad. Para que puedan ayudarte, debes mostrar lo que has conseguido. Dices que llevas varios dias intentandolo... pero ¿que has intentado?¿que has conseguido? Leyendo la documentación de como hacer una pregurnta, lo entrendaras y podras añadir el codigo y los ejemplos que hayas hecho hasta ahora. De no ser así, creo que nadie te hara el trabajo, incluso es posible que cierren tu pregunta. Suerte

Yo lo resolvería pasando al iFrame un token de autenticación como parámetro de la url y de ahí que la aplicación permita el acceso si detecta que se ha pasado un token.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

LA pagina no es mía, no entiendo completamente como puedo generar un token que la pagina que no me pertenece
